# IAM Policy for Cross-Account Lambda-ECR Access via Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

**What I want to do**: to be able to attach an image in ECR in one AWS account to a containerised Lambda function in another account **via the console**. Literally type the repository name, click the drop down, and select one of the images.

**What is this NOT about**: giving Lambda permission to access an image from a different account.

At the moment, the role I use cannot accomplish this, but there's a power user role that can, however its (YAML) configuration is opaque -- i.e. pretty much everything is a `*` and I'm not able to find out the exact policy that needs to be attached to my role which will let me access the images via the console. Could someone please help?